# How to create Bottom Up SwipeStack in android?

Tags: android, stackview

I want to create a bottom up swipe stack like the image below but in swipe should be in top and bottom. I have found one library but the swipe is there left and right.
https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack

The stack should have the following features.

1. If we are swiping up, left or right it should remove the item
2. If we are swiping down it should bring the old item

If anyone knows the library available like above mentioned please let me know.

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution yet?